# how to make multidimention array from looping

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

i try to make the pyramid on this loop + " " (space) and  then make it to be array, but that array not in one array, it seems separate not with the comma, u can check and run my codes below:

```js
var num = 5;

for(var i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++){
  var str = "";
  for(var j = 1 ; j <= num ; j++){
    str += j <= i ? j : ' '
  };
  var b = str.split("")
  console.log(b)
};
```

did you see the array ? 
they are not together,

how can i make that arry to be in one array like

```
[
  ["1", " ", " ", " ", " "],
  ["1", "2", " ", " ", " "],
  ["1", "2", "3", " ", " "],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", " "],
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You have done the main part of code to get the desired output.*

Declare an array outside the loop so that you can push all the items inside the loop:

```js
var num = 5;
var arr = [];
for(var i = 1 ; i <= num ; i++){
  var str = "";
  for(var j = 1 ; j <= num ; j++){
    str += j <= i ? j : ' '
  };
  arr.push(str.split(""));
};

console.log(arr);
```